# Why can't my variable equipmentNumber be reached?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have an application with 5 pages.

On the first page (`AdressPanel`), you enter some information like an equipmentNumber into a textfield. Then you click on a button in order to update the other pages and go to the next page (`LiftDataRevisionDocumentsPanel`). On there is a JLabel that should display the value that you have entered on page 1.

But no matter what I do, it does not show the entered value.

I have tried several keywords for the `equipmentNumber`: `static, final, public, private` but nothing changes. When I use final, I get the error message `the final field ... cannot be assigned`.

Note please: I am **NOT** using the earlier mentioned textfield in my example code, instead I try to put the string "1234567890" into `equipmentNumber` directly. Both ways don't work, see the ActionListener.

So why cant I reach the variable `equipmentNumber` / change the label on the second page?

```
public class TestApplication {
    static String equipmentNumber;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestApplication window = new TestApplication();
                    window.frmTool.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TestApplication() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frmTool = new JFrame();
        frmTool.setResizable(false);
        frmTool.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 850);
        frmTool.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmTool.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btnAdoptData1 = new JButton("Use Data");
        btnAdoptData1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                equipmentNumber = "1234567890";
                AdressPanel.setVisible(false);
                DangerJudgementScrollPane.setVisible(true);
                DangerJudgementContentPanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints gbc_btnAdoptData1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_btnAdoptData1.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        gbc_btnAdoptData1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_btnAdoptData1.gridx = 0;
        gbc_btnAdoptData1.gridy = 6;
        AdressPanel.add(btnAdoptData1, gbc_btnAdoptData1);

        JLabel lblEquipmentnumberRevisionDocuments = new JLabel(equipmentNumber);
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblEquipmentnumberRevisionDocuments = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblEquipmentnumberRevisionDocuments.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc_lblEquipmentnumberRevisionDocuments.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_lblEquipmentnumberRevisionDocuments.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblEquipmentnumberRevisionDocuments.gridy = 0;
        LiftDataRevisionDocumentsPanel.add(lblEquipmentnumberRevisionDocuments, gbc_lblEquipmentnumberRevisionDocuments);
```

Comment: The scope of a variable is not determined by it's type, rather how and where you declare it.

Comment: Objects don't have scopes. They have reachability. *Variables* have scopes, which are delimited by the nearest enclosing `{}` pair in most cases. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have changed the title of my questions since it does not seem to be a problem with the scope but instead with the reachability of my variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not one of scope or reachability but of order of execution.

`btnAdoptData1.addActionListener(...)` sets up an `ActionListener` to execute later when the button is clicked, then immediately returns and continues with the `initialize` method, which immediately creates the `new JLabel(equipmentNumber)`.

That means at the time when you create the `JLabel`, the `equipmentNumber` variable still has its default value, null. The `ActionListener` and the assignment `equipmentNumber = "1234567890"` don't execute until later.

If you want the `JLabel` to reflect the typed value, you'll need to set the label text only after it's been typed. E.g., do:

```
lblEquipmentnumberRevisionDocuments.setText(equipmentNumber);
```

when you show that page. Or don't create the label at all until you show that page.

Comment: Seems like I understand the order wrong in which components are added? I thought, page one is completed, then the String is set to `"1234567890"`, then the second page is created and with it the label. It's physically beneath the actionListener. Therefore my understanding must be wrong here?

Comment: Or to make it more clear: First, the whole application get's "constructed" and after that, the ActionListeners get added? It's not construced page-by-page (page 1 including ActionListener, then the next page with the label ...)?

Comment: You're creating all the components and their `ActionListeners` for both pages before any of it is shown. Calling `addActionListener` doesn't wait for the action to occur. It just sets up an `ActionListener` to be called later.